# Importação de Biblioteca dentro ou fora de funções

Tags: python

Eu queria saber se é correto importar bibliotecas dentro de funções? Ou é melhor importa a biblioteca no arquivo que a função for chamada, porém a função só funcionará se a biblioteca que a função necessita estiver sido importada previamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apesar de existirem casos onde importar a biblioteca dentro de uma função faz sentido, o mais comum e recomendado é que a biblioteca seja importada no cabeçalho do arquivo onde as funções da biblioteca são usadas.

Normalmente, é evidente quando você precisa importar uma biblioteca dentro de uma função. Se não for evidente, provavelmente você deve importa-la no cabeçalho.

Answer (score 4):

De acordo com o PEP-8:

"Imports devem ser sempre colocados no topo do arquivo, logo depois de quaisquer comentários ou docstrings, e antes de constantes ou globais. "

Segue o link com mais informações sobre o guia de estilo:

[Guia de Estilo](https://wiki.python.org.br/GuiaDeEstilo)